# Group wise object representation in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have below mongodb collection.

```
{
    "studCode":"S-110",
    "studName":"ABC PQR XYZZ",
    "dept":
          {
            "_id":"83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department":
          {
          "departmentName":"Dept A"
          }
       }
},

{
    "studCode":"S-112",
    "studName":"ABC PQR XYZZ",
    "dept":
          {
            "_id":"83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department":
          {
          "departmentName":"Dept B"
          }
       }
},

{
    "studCode":"S-113",
    "studName":"शABC PQR XYZZ",
    "dept":
          {
            "_id":"83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department":
          {
          "departmentName":"Dept B"
          }
       }
},

{
    "studCode":"S-114",
    "studName":"शABC PQR XYZZ",
    "dept":
          {
            "_id":"83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department":
          {
          "departmentName":"Dept A"
          }
       }
}
```

I want to show DepartmentNamewise student details in angular js.
like

```
Dept A:
1) "studCode":"S-114",
    "studName":"शABC PQR XYZZ"
2)"studCode":"S-110",
    "studName":"ABC PQR XYZZ"
```

Note: The objectis not from single collection. I gathered data from different collections and made its object so could not use group by or something like that in mongo.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if it's not actually from a single "collection" ( not called tables here ) then perhaps you should show the work you have done so far to collect from the individual sources. Then: What have you actually tried? What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: Actually Students collection is there , it contains student details and dept code.From that dept code in Students collection, I taken dept object from department collection and assigned it as student.dept... Now I want to show students deprtment wise on angular js page

Answer (score 0):

Assuiming that you have an array of above objects. You can use `groupBy` to filter out the student details based on department.

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.students = [{
        "studCode": "S-110",
        "studName": "ABC PQR XYZZ",
        "dept": {
            "_id": "83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department": {
                "departmentName": "Dept A"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "studCode": "S-112",
        "studName": "ABC PQR XYZZ",
        "dept": {
            "_id": "83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department": {
                "departmentName": "Dept B"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "studCode": "S-113",
        "studName": "शABC PQR XYZZ",
        "dept": {
            "_id": "83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department": {
                "departmentName": "Dept B"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "studCode": "S-114",
        "studName": "शABC PQR XYZZ",
        "dept": {
            "_id": "83bc3f57-4ef7-51ea-2052-d989541682e f",
            "department": {
                "departmentName": "Dept A"
            }
        }
    }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.1/angular-filter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<meta name="description" content="[groupBy and sum example]" />
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>angular-filter - groupBy and sum example</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in students | groupBy: 'dept.department.departmentName'">
        <tr>
            <th>
                {{key}}
            </th>
            <th>count:{{value.length}}</th>
        </tr>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="student in value">
                <td>
                    {{student.studName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{student.studCode}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :)can we get count of records under Dept A , Dept B and like wise i.e group wise count

Comment: I have updated my code with the count. You can style the table to your requirements.